# Jquery Performance - Paginate logic

Tags: jquery, html, performance, pagination

Am having huge HTML content in a DOM and trying to paginate with some fixed height for each page

i have written logic which go through entire DOM and assign each element a class name which will contain what page the element can go into

```
<div>
<p class="pg_1">Some Content</P>
<p class="pg_1">Some Content</P>
<ol class="pg_1">
<li class="pg_1">1</li>
<li class="pg_1">2</li>
<li class="pg_1">3</li>
<li class="pg_1">4</li>
</ol>
<p class="pg_1">Some Content</P>
<ol class="pg_1 pg_2">
<li class="pg_1">1</li>
<li class="pg_1">2</li>
<li class="pg_2">3</li>
<li class="pg_2">4</li>
</ol>
<p class="pg_2">Some Content</P>
<p class="pg_2">Some Content</P>
<p class="pg_2">Some Content</P>
<div class="pg_2"> Some Big contensts </div>
<!--Large page content and goes upto 1000 -->
<p class="pg_1000">Some Content</P>
</div>
```

Currently lets assume i have content from DOM into a variable  source and now looping through source am trying to go through DOM every time to extract each page and append to a variable which is hitting performance badly

```
  // i having this in a for loop i incrementing i so i traverse each page
    var page =   source.find('[class*=pg]').each(function () {
           if ($(this).is(".pg_"+i)) return;
           $(this).remove();
           });
```

Currently to extract each page am going through entire content  every time and finding the pages which is hitting performance badly.

is there a better way i can handle this to improve performance. am looking to get content as per the class separately based on **.pg_1 , .pg_2** etc

Any suggestion or question if i  have not written what i need correctly !!!

Comment: Did you look at jqgrid?

Comment: @MisterPositive  jqgrid might be better for table of contents. i need to manipulate same as DOM with header footer images etc so i need to go for custom logic